# Finding Documents Based on Date inside Array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've got a schema similar to this:

```
{ 
  'policy': [
    { 'date' : { type: Date } }
  ]
}
```

I'm attempting to find these based on the first policy's date, based on a range.  At first when my queries like this were silently failing (i.e. returning no results):

```
{
  '$and' : [
    { 'policy.0.date' : { '$gt' : <lower-bound Date> } },
    { 'policy.0.date' : { '$lt' : <higher-bound Date> } }
  ]
}
```

I wasn't getting any errors, and I knew there were records there, so I pared it down to looking for all who were above a certain date:

```
{ 'policy.0.date' : { $gt : startDate } }
```

After attempting that, I got this error:

```
[Error: Can't use $gt with Array.]
```

I've even tried to querying without being based on the first element `{ 'policy.date' : { $gt : startDate } }`, but that returns no records either.

Any ideas on how to query on the date field without resorting to `$where`?

Comment: Which version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: We're currently running v2.4.3, been meaning to update it.

Comment: and the query works on mongo shell?

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work, no.  Inside the `mongo` shell it doesn't give me any errors either.  I may be setting the date variable wrong however, when I do `var nsDate = new Date().setDate(1)` then `nsDate.getDate()` it gives me a weird message `Mon Jul 15 09:58:39.005 JavaScript execution failed: TypeError: Object 1372687097184 has no method 'getDate'`.

Comment: @MiguelCartagena This date behavior may be normal in `mongo` though.

Comment: when you do `new Date().setDate(1)`, it return a long not a date/isodate object. I did some [tests](https://gist.github.com/cartagena/6000110) that worked properly, check this out.

Comment: Hrm, I think the issue lies in the version of Mongoose/ MongoDB driver we're using.  The DB itself does allow for queries like this.

Comment: please test using Mongoose 3.6.14. If it still is an issue, please open a ticket: https://github.com/learnboost/mongoose/issues/new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem actual DB queries return correctly, the issues lies in the version of mongoose used.